# How can I submit Hcaptcha without a confirmation button. (2Captcha/Dbc)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, captcha, 2captcha

I using an API to break HCaptcha perhaps I don't know how can I submit it.

In Recaptcha I just need to call the callback function and insert the token `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback("TOKENCAPTCHA")`, but in HCaptcha I don't see that.

What I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response')[0].innerHTML = '{token}';
document.getElementsByName('g-recaptcha-response')[0].innerHTML = '{token}';
```

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188276/cant-submit-captcha-textfield-python-selenium): "CAPTCHA ... is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try!"